# How to copy files from one computer to another in Ubuntu crontab?

Tags: linux, cron

I have two computers one Ubuntu server and a backup computer. I want to daily copy files to backup computer at particular.

My code goes below

```
15 16 * * * root sshpass -p password scp -rv /home/BACKUP xyx@192.168.0.4:/home/Desktop/
```

I searched many answer but end up with code above which isn't working. Help me copy files to another computer in crontab.

Comment: Take a look to rsync: https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio please show me according to problem above. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy files from cron using ssh, is better to use an asymetric-key validation mechanism. You must create a pair of public/private keys in machine is running task from cron:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

this will add private key information to ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Then, you must copy content of ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on **remote** machine. That way, you are not going to be asked for password every time.

Oh!, and use **rsync**. Is better, because is incremental. Maybe **rnapshot** will do it better for you,

Comment: Tried for 3 hours and worked. I am copying from server to a normal computer. So I created keygen stuff in the server. Copied id_rsa.pub to normal computer in ~/.ssh/ and renamed authorized_keys. In /etc/crontab I did ***scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -r folder xys@ip:/home/